# Difficulty understanding a SQL Join query

Tags: sql

I have these tables in my database:

**Student**:

```
id,
style_id,
instrument,
name,
```

**Teacher**:

```
id,
style_id,
name
```

**lessons**:

```
id,
style_id,
teacher_id,
student_id,
month
```

And I'm trying to write a query that returns every student enrolled for a particular month and their teacher and style e.g. it would return something like this:

**March**

```
Student Name   Teacher   Style
-------------------------------
Glen           Bob       Jazz
Missy          Bruce     Rock
```

So far all I got is something like this (I know I need to use joins just don't know how):

```
SELECT 
    students.name, teacher.name, style.style_name 
FROM 
    lessons 
WHERE 
    month = "March" 
JOINS students, teachers
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, it is not a good practice for you to have the name of the table in your primary key, in your table teacher, you used musician_id, use  teacher_id instead. This is the code I would use to achieve what you are trying to do.

`SELECT a.style_name, b.name, c.name, d.month`
`FROM lessons d`
`INNER JOIN Styles a ON a.style_id = d.style_id`
`INNER JOIN Student b ON b.student_id = d.student_id`
`INNER JOIN Teacher c ON c.teacher_id = d.teacher_id`
`WHERE d.month = "march";`

Since you are in difficulty with joins, Inner join, will see if its evidence of the ids in both tables to return true, thats why it solvs your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question,

```
SELECT Student.name AS Student, Teacher.name AS Teacher, Styles.style_name AS Style
FROM lessons 
INNER JOIN Styles ON lessons.style_id = Styles.style_id 
INNER JOIN Teacher ON lessons.teacher_id = Teacher.musician_id 
INNER JOIN Student ON lessons.student_id = Student.student_id
WHERE lessons.month="March";
```

You might want to look at your table design, though.  You have a style_id in the lessons, the Teachers and the Students tables.  The query above matches the style name with the style_id in the lessons table, while it could be linked to either the Teacher table or the Student table.  This could lead to reporting problems if Bob is teaching a Jazz lesson and his profile says he's a Rock teacher.

It's better to remove the style_id from the Teacher and Student tables and introduce a new table 
**Interests**: participant_id (could be teacher id or student id), role ('teacher' or 'student'), style_id